# Conditional Statements in Power BI: Help greatly appreciated

Tags: date, powerbi, conditional-statements, dax, powerbi-desktop

I would be very grateful for any assistance on solving the below.

I have a table in Microsoft Power BI Desktop containing 2 types of columns: 1 column containing unique employee IDs (column labeled "Employee ID"), and several other columns marking the date when (if ever) an individual completed a specific task (columns labeled "Task 1," "Task 2," "Task 3," etc.).  If an employee completes a given task, s/he receives a bonus.

Using Power BI Desktop, what is the best way to accomplish the following objectives:

(1) Assign a numerical value to the completion of each of these tasks/columns (i.e., the bonus), such that future business users (read: non-developers) can adjust the value/bonus as it changes year to year.

(2) Allow business years to manually enter (a) an employee ID and (b) a fiscal year (e.g., 2021), with the result that Power BI determines whether that employee completed any of the tasks within that fiscal year, and returns the sum total of the values assigned above for all those tasks/columns.

Thank you very much for your assistance! = )

Answer (score 0):

For your second objective:

The easiest way is to prepare a report (visualizations - tables / charts) and add appropriate filters / slicers. The user will then be able to select the year and the employee.

For the first: it depends on what you really mean by assigning a numerical value.

You can prepare a table containing the bonus value for a given task/year. And then a measure referring to it. (e.g. LOOKUPVALUE)